# stuck in white screen after splash screen on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to deploy an minimalistic app using expo (and react native). I have set up a splash screen and 4 other screens. Everything works fine when running `expo start` (both on ios and android). However when i try to create an dev build, `eas build -p ios --profile preview`, the build runs perfectly but when the app starts i see the splash screen then a white screen. Here are the important files:

```
{
  "name": "apotheca",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-file-system": "^15.2.2",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "^12.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.18.2",
    "expo-sqlite": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "^0.16.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

the App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { Modal, Pressable } from 'react-native';

import PlantsSearchScreen from './screens/plantsSearch';
import PlantDetailsScreen from './screens/plantsDetails';
import PropertiesSearchScreen from './screens/propertiesSearch';
import PropertyDetailsScreen from './screens/propertyDetails';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const PlantStack = createStackNavigator();
const PropertyStack = createStackNavigator();

const PlantsStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <PlantStack.Navigator>
      <PlantStack.Screen   name="Plants"
        component={PlantsSearchScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' },
        }}
      />
      <PlantStack.Screen   name="Plant Details"
        component={PlantDetailsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          headerBackTitle: 'Back',
          headerBackTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 20,
          },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' },
        }}
      />
      <PlantStack.Screen  name="Property Details"
        component={PropertyDetailsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          headerBackTitle: 'Back',
          headerBackTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 20,
          },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' },
        }}
      />
    </PlantStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const PropertiesStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <PropertyStack.Navigator>
      <PropertyStack.Screen name="Properties"
        component={PropertiesSearchScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' },
        }}
      />
      <PropertyStack.Screen name="Property Details"
        component={PropertyDetailsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          headerBackTitle: 'Back',
          headerBackTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 20,
          },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' },
        }}
      />
      <PropertyStack.Screen name="Plant Details"
        component={PlantDetailsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          headerBackTitle: 'Back',
          headerBackTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique',
            fontSize: 20,
          },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' },
        }}
      />
    </PropertyStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
  const [fontLoadTimeout, setFontLoadTimeout] = useState(false);

  const handleUnderstoodPress = () => {

    setModalVisible(false);
   
  };

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'CaslonAntique': require('./assets/fonts/CaslonAntique.ttf'), 
    'CaslonAntique-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/CaslonAntique-Bold.ttf'),
    'CaslonAntique-Italic': require('./assets/fonts/CaslonAntique-Italic.ttf'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setFontLoadTimeout(true);
     }, 10000); // Set a 10-second timeout

     return () => clearTimeout(timer);
   }, []);

   if (!fontsLoaded) {
     if (fontLoadTimeout) {
       return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
           <Text>Error loading fonts. Please restart the app or check your internet connection.</Text>
         </View>
       );
     }
     return <View />;
   }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>
              Disclaimer: This app is intended for informational purposes only and should not be used as a substitute for professional medical advice. Always consult a healthcare professional if you have any concerns or doubts. The posology information provided in this app is not a medical recommendation and may be harmful if used without proper guidance from a healthcare professional.
            </Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={handleUnderstoodPress}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Understood</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{tabBarLabelStyle: {fontFamily: 'CaslonAntique', fontSize: 20},
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#e2cca7' ,
        borderTopWidth: 2, // Add this line to create a black line above the bottom bar
        paddingTop: 10,
        borderTopColor: 'black' // Add this line to set the line color to black
      },
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#222222',
        headerShown: false,}}
      >

      <Tab.Screen
          name="PlantsTab"
          component={PlantsStackNavigator}
          options={{
            title: '', // Set this to an empty string
            tabBarLabel: 'Plants',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
              <Image
                source={require('./assets/plant-icon.png')}
                style={{ width: size, height: size, tintColor: color }}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
         <Tab.Screen
          name="PropertiesTab"
          component={PropertiesStackNavigator}
          options={{
            title: '', // Set this to an empty string
            tabBarLabel: 'Properties',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
              <Image
                source={require('./assets/mortar.png')}
                style={{ width: size, height: size, tintColor: color }}
              />
            ),

          }}
        />

      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I am wondering if the loading of the fonts can get stuck and prevent the screen from loading?
otherwise I have a standard app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Apotheca",
    "slug": "Apotheca",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/apothecarySplash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#e2cca7"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.compagnyName.Apotheca"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#e2cca7"
      }
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "...."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I looked for the xcode logs, build logs, change some parts of the code but nothing seems to help. What could be the issue? (note i have the same issue on android where it is stuck on splashscreen)

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/ per the documentation, you have to hide the splashscreen after the fonts are loaded otherwise dont hide

Comment: indeed there is a problem when loading the font (but no problem with expo start)..
i added the ttf file to the metro.config but still have the issue .. any ideas why the fonts are not detected?

Comment: yes, use the exact same code from the documentaion in the useeffect, a timeout is useless in these cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAy be you shoold look into it.
[github](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1036)
[EAS](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1036)

Comment: using     "@react-navigation/native-stack" instead of   "@react-navigation/stack":
fixed it